# Error ModuleNotFoundError with python3 reinstalling Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, software-installation, python, python3

I have a server with a broken python3 installation in a remote location accessible only via ssh.
Most of the solutions to this problem I've googled have eventually boiled down to reinstalling the OS.
Simpler commands like

`apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-server`

fail with the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...` as follows

```
Preparing to unpack .../dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg (1.19.7ubuntu3) over (1.19.7ubuntu3) ...
Setting up dpkg (1.19.7ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.8-minimal.
(Reading database ... 112481 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3.8-minimal_3.8.5-1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.8-minimal (3.8.5-1~20.04) ...
Setting up python3.8-minimal (3.8.5-1~20.04) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3.8'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 1
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3.8'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3.8'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f862a82a740 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3.8-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.8-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.8-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm stymied. Does anyone have a suggestion to repair the broken python3?

Answer (score 1):

**apt** cannot help you because it needs the broken Python 3.
**dpkg** does not need Python 3, so you can use it for the re-installation of Python 3.
However, it does not handle dependencies automatically, so you must install them in an order that functions.

1. Search for a suitable `python3` for your distro in the https://packages.ubuntu.com/
2. For example, for focal (Ubuntu 20.04) in a few clicks you land on the package page: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3
3. That page lists with red bullets which other packages are **dependencies** of `python3` and should be installed first. In this example

   1. `python3.8-minimal`
   2. `python3-minimal`
   3. `libpython3-stdlib`

   It looks like that:

   [image]

   Click on the names of those dependencies and download the deb files for your architecture on your computer. This is the area where you do that:

   [image]
4. Install the deb files that you downloaded with

   `sudo dpkg -i [package name].deb`

   dpkg will throw an error if you should try a different order of installation or if other dependencies are missing in their turn.

   Do not forget to finish with installing the main package of Python 3 after its dependencies (point 2).

   Optionally you can do `sudo dpkg -a --configure` to check whether all packages are actually in order.
5. After Python 3 has been repaired, apt should work again.